# playframework javascript asset JSLint processing : info message "Javascript linting on x source(s)

Tags: javascript, playframework, jslint

I have two Javascript files that I wrote in my app/assets/javascripts directory of my java playframework 2.4 application.

I am always seeing the message in the console:

```
[info] JavaScript linting on 1 source(s)
```

What does this mean? I can't find any documentation on it. I suppose it is talking about JSLint here, which would mean that play is sending my javascript through the JSLint parser to check for bad code.

Is that right?

Great if so. Except, Now I am worried about the message. Yes it is only info. But is it nonetheless somehow significant? I have two Javascript files. It is only mentioning one. Which one? I have no idea! No mention of it in the application.log

What's the best way to find out just what it is referring to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That log message is produced by the sbt-jshint plugin, wich will lint the files in `src/main/assets/**/*.js` and `src/test/assets/**/*.js` whenever one is created or modified.

That log message is only for information purposes. As far as I known, it doesn't mention wich file is processing and I don't think it's important. If a javascript file has any error, it will be shown on the browser on the app page, just like a compilation error.

You can check the plugin documentation [here](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-jshint).